# Java Array TopCustomers

Tags: java, sorting, recursion, arraylist, while-loop

I'm currently trying to working through a problem with `ArrayList`.

This is supposed to take the input of the user and customers sales and display the top customer. Yet, I'm having and issue with an inner `while`.

Using VSCODE. The inner while is throwing an error within the inner if `sales.get(j) > largest`) stating the > is undefined.

Please, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TopCusomters {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
    ArrayList sales = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList customers = new ArrayList();
    int numOfItems = 0;
    double price = 0;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean entryComplete = false;
    do {
        System.println("Customers Names");
        customers.add(in.next());       
        System.println("Sales of the Customer (0 to end):");
        price = in.nextDouble();
        sales.add(price);
        numOfItems++;
        }while(price != 0 && mumOfItems < 100);
        System.out.println("Please provide values of N");
        int topN = in.nextInt();
        ArrayList topCustomers = nameOfBestCustomers(sales, customers, topN);
        System.out.println(" Top Customers list" + "is" + topCustomers.toString());
    }
    public static ArrayList nameOfBestCustomers (ArrayList sales,ArrayList customers, int topN)
    {
        ArrayList bestCustomers = new ArrayList();
        sortCustomers(sales,customers);
        int i = 0;
        while (i)
        {
            bestCustomers.add(customers.get(i));
               i++;
        }
        return bestCustomers;
    }
    public static void sortCustomers(ArrayList sales, ArrayList customers)
    {
        int i = 0;
        double temp = 0;
        String tempName = "";
        while (i)
        {
            double largest = sales.get(i);
            int largestIndex = i;
            int j = i;
            while (j)
            {
                if(sales.get(j) > largest)
                {
                    largest = sales.get(j);
                    largestIndex = j;                
                }
                i++;
            }
        temp = sales.get(i);
        sales.set(i,sales.get(largestIndex));
        sales.set(largestIndex,temp);
        tempName = customers.get(i);
        customers.set(i,customers.get(largestIndex));
        customers.set(largestIndex, tempName);
        i++;    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: while needs a boolean expression. int is not allowed. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not specifying object types that lists are holding for below declarations ,

```
ArrayList sales = new ArrayList();
ArrayList customers = new ArrayList();
```

So when you retrieve objects from list and try to apply operators, Java doesn't know which type its working on. ( Java assumes `java.lang.Object` and operator `>` doesn't make sense on `Object` )

For long term solution , declarations should be changed as below or you can try that after explicit cast too,

```
List<Double> sales = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> customers = new ArrayList<>();
```

where Double is `java.lang.Double`

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList` without type will default to `ArrayList<Object>`, that means that `sales.get(j)`'s return value is `Object`. You probably want `ArrayList<Double>`.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple syntax errors, for example:

1. Conditional expression like `while (<expr>) { ... }` need to evaluate to `boolean`. `while(i)` is not a valid expression, see 
   [The while and do-while Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) docs.
2. `do { ... }` is not a valid Java construct, most likely you tried to use a do-while loop `do { ... } while (<expr>);` loop.
3. You are using rawtype `ArrayList`. Most likely it should be `List<Double>`. You need generics to compare `sales` elements with `double largest` using auto-boxing, see [Lesson: Generics (Updated)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html) docs.